# Merge mp3 files using FFmpeg on Android

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am trying to merge two mp3 files using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:/storage/emulated/0/Recordings/oneone.mp3|/storage/emulated/0/Recordings/twone.mp3" -c copy /storage/emulated/0/Recordings/concated.mp3
```

but get this error:

```
"concat:/storage/emulated/0/Recordings/oneone.mp3|/storage/emulated/0/Recordings/twone.mp3": No such file or directory
```

Even though the both files exist in the directory. I have written this command according to the documentation: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol

How do I fix this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have read and write permissions on the device? Because from my experience the below command works perfectly fine.

```
 ffmpeg -i "concat:/sdcard/test1.mp3|/sdcard/test2.mp3" -acodec copy /sdcard/output.mp3
```