# Merge mp3 files at specific duration in Android

Tags: android, audio, merge, ffmpeg

First I'm new in Android.

I'm trying to make an app that can combine a lot of music(mp3 files im using) **at specific duration** with the selected music via seekbar.

My main plan is to **merge multiple audio files at specific time**.

example:
when i pressed the drum button at 5 sec(via seekbar), and then guitar button at 6 sec.

when i clicked the merge button, it will merged the selected mp3 file with those 2 mp3 files at their respective time.

from what i'm searching so far, the possible way is by using **ffmpeg** from this :

-[How to overlay two audio files using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498539/how-to-overlay-two-audio-files-using-ffmpeg)

-[Merge mp3 files using FFmpeg on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715702/merge-mp3-files-using-ffmpeg-on-android)

but i don't see them merged at specified time.

maybe there's another way besides **ffmpeg**,or i've missed something?

thank you

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1092346/114058

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks for your respond!